How to calculate continuous Fourier inverse numerically with numpy?
I'm trying to implement a function that calculates the inverse Fourier transform of a continuous function F(ω) to obtain f(x).
My input function is continuous (you can assume it is a lambda function) so I have to approximate it discretely using discrete sampling. Here's my current implementation:
import numpy as np

def fourier_inverse(f, n, omega_max):
    """
    :param f: The function to be transformed
    :param n: Number of samples
    :param omega_max: The max frequency we want to be samples
    """
    omega_range = np.linspace(-omega_max, omega_max, n)
    f_values = f(omega_range, sigma, alpha)
    inverse_f = np.fft.ifftshift(np.fft.ifft(np.fft.fftshift(f_values)))
    return inverse_f

However, I have two main concerns:

The x-axis of the result ranges from 0 to n, which doesn't seem
correct. I don't know how to approach it.
I'm unsure if the overall approach is correct, particularly
regarding the sampling and normalization.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

You cannot compute a Fourier transform using NumPy. You are computing a Discrete Fourier Transform, which is different from a Fourier Transform. You need symbolic math, take a look at SymPy.

@CrisLuengo I'm trying to approximate it using Discrete Fourier Transform. My inverted function may not have symbolic representation.

Unless your function is band-limited, and approaches zero at some point on both ends, you cannot sample it and get a meaningful DFT (or IDFT) from it. — Band-limited means that the transform also approaches zero at some point on both ends, and hence can also be sampled.

@CrisLuengo It does approach to zero. It's a form of Gaussian function. I want to replicate the second GIF in this website: https://jacopobertolotti.com/FractionalDerivativesIntro.html

Yeah, that seems doable. Thanks for the clarification!

You can calculate the Fourier transform using:
np.fft.ifftshift(np.fft.ifft(np.fft.fftshift(f(omega_range))))



lambda x: np.exp(-x ** 2) is a Gaussian function.
np.fft.ifftshift(np.fft.fftfreq(n, d=delta_omega)) is spatial range.
delta_omega * n / (2 * np.pi) normalizes the iFFt.

import numpy as np


def fourier_inverse(f, n, omega_max):
    omega_range = np.linspace(-omega_max, omega_max, n)
    f_values = np.fft.ifftshift(np.fft.ifft(np.fft.fftshift(f(omega_range))))
    delta_omega = 2 * omega_max / n
    x_range = np.fft.ifftshift(np.fft.fftfreq(n, d=delta_omega))
    f_values *= delta_omega * n / (2 * np.pi)
    return x_range, f_values


x, f = fourier_inverse(lambda x: np.exp(-x ** 2), 512, 10)

print(x, f)


Thanks. But It seems the x_range is incorrect. If I'm not wrong, it should be x_max = np.pi / delta_omega  \n   x_range = np.linspace(-x_max, x_max, n)
